# Angular 7 HttpClient put request params sending null values to endpoint

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, angular-httpclient

I have an Angular service with this Put request method:

```
put(peopleFieldID: number, peopleFieldName: string): Observable<number> {
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append("peopleFieldID", peopleFieldID.toString());
params = params.append("peopleFieldName", peopleFieldName);

return this.http
  .put<number>(this.url, { params: params })
  .pipe(catchError(this._errorHandling.handleError.bind(this)));}
```

The above hits this endpoint on my .net core API:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Client")]
    [Route("")]
    [HttpPut]
    public IActionResult C_Update(int peopleFieldID, string peopleFieldName )
    {
        //Make call to the proper repo method.
        return Json(_peopleFieldRepo.C_Update(peopleFieldID, peopleFieldName));
    }
```

The two params, peopleFieldID and peopleFieldName, are always 0 and null. I have pinpointed that the Angular frontend sends the params correctly, but the backend cannot recognize them. I have many other endpoints where this works just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set query params using `HttpParams` and pass `null` for payload if you do not have any:

```
const params = new HttpParams()
            .set('peopleFieldID', peopleFieldID.toString())
            .set('peopleFieldName', peopleFieldName);
// if you have a payload to pass you can do that in place of null below
return this.http
  .put<number>(this.url, null, { params: params })
  .pipe(catchError(this._errorHandling.handleError.bind(this)));}
```

Comment: This did solve the issue. I thought because the body param was optional, that it wouldn't matter if I did not include it. I don't include it on Get requests, but it makes sense why I would need it on Post/Puts. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, you don't need the body for Get but Put and POST need it , so send null if you don't have any need.